# MVC 3 with IIS Express Odd Redirecting behavior

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-express

I have a simple MVC 3 webapp that's been giving me trouble lately - and nowhere I look seems to have any information that can help me. I've been having two issues that seem related in how they're behaving.

In development, it starts fine on localhost (http://localhost:53268/) and works for the index, but doing anything outside of that has IIS returning a 404, ignoring any redirecting to what should be a proper URL.

Now, in production, it behaves differently. Again, the index page works fine, it has the proper URL, but any other page (either through a link or going directly to the URL) redirects to localhost (https://localhost/). The odd thing is for me, it's working as it should be on development (giving me what I should be seeing when I usually get 404s), but on other machines it gives absolutely nothing.

I had inherited this from a co-worker who had since left, but had given me the advice of using IIS Express to get it working from the development side. This was already working in production before, but now... not so much.

**EDIT**
The global.aspx file

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Got it figured out. Turns out there were some issues with Web.Config and the server it was on getting the wrong one. Works fine now.

Comment: Post the Global.asax code for creating routes.

Comment: Are you by any chance using a virtual directory like this local host/blah/index

Comment: can you post the code that does the redirects and if it is a link can you post the view code? also can you post your route table configuration of your global.asax...

Comment: I put in the global.asax

Comment: @Goat, I don't see any code that performs a redirect in what you have shown.

Comment: What version of IIS do you have on the server and other machines where its giving 404s?

Comment: @jrummell I'm using IIS 7.5 both my machine and the server it's hosted on